# Android Studio 3: APK Keeps Being Sent to Unwanted Release Folder

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I believe this has only occurred with AS 3, but my signed apks keep being sent to `C:/.../Android_App_Builds/release` instead of just `C:/.../Android_App_Builds` along with an output json. This could be a default behavior for using the release build type, but it is rather annoying that it doesn't specify the directory exactly as is.

I suppose the alternative is to accept the release folder and just put it in a build folder for that specific app.